# Mongoid with custom id and factoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid, factory-bot, mongoid3

I have the following code:

factories/web.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :web do
    name 'Name of web'
    url 'http://google.es'

    after(:create) do |web|
      10.times do |i|
        web.link << FactoryGirl.create(:link, web: web, url: i, _id: i)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

factories/link.rb

```
factory :link do
  anchor_text 'anchor'
  title 'title'
  code 200
  sequence :url do |n|
    "http://google.es/#{n}"
  end
end
```

models/web.rb

```
class Web
  include Mongoid::Document
  (...)
  has_many :link
end
```

models/link.rb

```
class Link
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :_id, type: String, default: ->{ Digest::MD5.hexdigest(url) }
  belongs_to :web
  field :url, type: String
  (...)
end
```

So I have a custom id in Link, it works in development enviroment but when I ran rspec, I am getting in all tests:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
TypeError:
can't convert nil into String
# ./app/models/link.rb:4:in `digest'
# ./app/models/link.rb:4:in `hexdigest'
# ./app/models/link.rb:4:in `block in <class:Link>'
# ./spec/factories/webs.rb:10:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/factories/webs.rb:9:in `times'
# ./spec/factories/webs.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/factories/user.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try write:

```
factory :link do
  sequence(:url) { |n| "http://google.es/#{n}" }

  anchor_text 'anchor'
  title 'title'
  code 200
  url
end
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I will get an error as:
Trait not registered